# DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory - ConcurrentHashMap - NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using kafka consumer. i did an upgrade from Spring boot 1.5 to 2.6. now when i run the applicaiton, its failing to start throwing NullPointerException . please let me know if any one could help me on this issue.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putAll(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1084) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.<init>(ConcurrentHashMap.java:852) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.<init>(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:129) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.<init>(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:98) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]

Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory
```

pom.xml

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </parent>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

### ReceiverConfigClass:

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@ExcludeKafkaReceiver
public class XXTriggerKakfaReceiverConfig {
   
    @Autowired
    xxTriggerKafkaManagedBean kafkaListenerConfig;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> xxConsumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaListenerConfig.getKafkaServerConfig());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getKafkaServerConfig());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, MessageSerializerType.getValue(kafkaListenerConfig.getValueDeserializerClass()));
        props.put(Constants.AVRO_MSG_CLASS_TYPE, kafkaListenerConfig.getAvroMessageClassType());
        // consumer groups allow a pool of processes to divide the work of
        // consuming and processing records
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getPartitionAssignmentStrategy());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getGroupId());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getAutoOffsetReset());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getEnableAutoCommit());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getSessionTimeoutMS());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getHeartbeatIntervalMS());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getRequestTimeoutMS());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getFetchMaxWaitMS());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getReconnectBackoffMS());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getRetryBackoffMS());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getMaxPartitionFetchSize());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getFetchMinBytes());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, kafkaListenerConfig.getMaxPollRecords());

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> xxConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(xxConsumerConfigs());  //This is the place throwing Null pointer Exception
    }

    /**
     * A concurrent Kafka listener with concurrency managed through {concurrent_kafka_listeners} property value.
     *
     * @return ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory instance 
     */
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> xxKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(xxConsumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(kafkaListenerConfig.getNumberOfConcurrentListeners());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        ErrorHandler errorHandler = new KafkaListenerErrorHandler();
        errorHandler.setAckAfterHandle(false);        
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler((CommonErrorHandler) errorHandler);
        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * A concurrent Kafka batch listener with concurrency managed through {concurrent_kafka_listeners} property value.
     *
     * @return ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory instance
     */
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> xxKafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(xxConsumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(kafkaListenerConfig.getNumberOfConcurrentListeners());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        ErrorHandler errorHandler = new KafkaListenerErrorHandler(); 
        errorHandler.setAckAfterHandle(false);        
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler((CommonErrorHandler) errorHandler);
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        return factory;
    }
```

Comment: That exception is thrown on the `this.configs = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(configs);`. So, looks like something in your `xxConsumerConfigs` is really `null`.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.6 uses Spring 5.3, you have Spring 5.2 dependencies in there.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error where before the Springboot upgrade (v2.2.4 -> v2.7.3), the code was working fine and post-upgrade, it started throwing a `NullPointerException`. I would strongly recommend debugging the code and go inside Spring libraries to understand which exact property is failing. In my case, it was

```
    SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG=
or
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

which had been working fine as a `null` before the upgrade. But after the upgrade, it had to be set to an empty String due to changes in Kafka library.

Found help from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56648768/4898612.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure all the values fetched from kafkaListenerConfig are not null, i.e. props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, **kafkaListenerConfig.getKafkaServerConfig**());

If one of the required parameter is null, DefaultKafkaConsumer throws NPE.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35158521)