# What is the equivalent of enable.ssl.certificate.verification from librdkafka in Kafka Client Scala Library

Tags: scala, ssl, apache-kafka

We are testing the new TLS configuration in our Kafka Clusters in Test Environment, and we have two types of consumers on using `librdkafka` and other using Kafka Consumers in Scala.

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=none
enable.ssl.certificate.verification=false
```

This work fine with our `kafkacat`, and also our libraries with `librdkafka`.

But if I try to connect with our Scala connector the configuration `enable.ssl.certificate.verification` doesn't exists in the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_security.protocol)

I would like to know what is the equivalent of `enable.ssl.certificate.verification` in the Kafka consumers in Scala or Java. This is just to proceed with our testing. Is there anyway to connect with SSL without the certificate using the Scala Library?

Comment: In Java/Scala, when you enable SSL you also enable the verification, so I would advise to be sure to generate the keys, certificates, keystores/truststores used by Kafka. If you don't want SSL certificate validation you should not use SSL in the first place. By the way, SSL is deprecated and should not be used in production. Default value for ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip yep I do understand that and that is why is just for some testing in our side. We were expecting to run a quick test in our test environment with the different types of languages we use. Our Scala connectors are the last one to the test, and the quickest way to do it was using this verification false on the other ones.

Comment: could those properties be helpful?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54903381/kafka-failed-authentication-due-to-ssl-handshake-failed